# Magento set stock while importing

Tags: magento, import

I'm importing some products into my shop but the stockdata doesn't get set.

```
$simpleProduct->setStockData(array(
    'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
    'manage_stock'=>1,
    'min_sale_qty'=>1,
    'is_in_stock' => 1,
    'qty' => 999
    )
);


$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
$stockItem->assignProduct($Simpleproduct);
$stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 1);
$stockItem->setData('qty', 999);
$simpleProduct->setStockItem($stockItem);
```

Both code snippets don't work and set manage stock to no and no availible qty.

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works:

```
$productID = ID //Your product ID
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($productID);
 /* Product stock doesn't exist? create a new one */
if (empty($stockItem->getProductId())) {
    $stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 1);
    $stockItem->setData('use_config_manage_stock', 0);
    $stockItem->setData('stock_id', 1);
    $stockItem->setData('product_id', $productID);
    $stockItem->save();
}

 /* Initialize the stock object to get the full object */
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($productID);

 /* Set the quantity */
$stockItem->setData('qty', 999);
$stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 1);
$stockItem->save();
```

Comment: When you are using `loadByProduct` shouldn't it be the product rather than productID?

Comment: @James No. In magento mainly models keep the product ID rather than the product itself as a reference to the product.